# Conditional probability of two variables given a binary one

Tags: probability, independence

I was having trouble understanding a particular instance of probability independence. Let $X,Y$ be two random variables and $Z$ be a binary-valued variable. If $X \perp Y \vert z^0$ is it true that $X \perp Y \vert Z$? What I being trying is writing $P(X,Y \vert z^1) $ in terms of $P(X,Y \vert z^0) $ using Bayes Rule and the fact that $P(z^1 \vert X,Y) = 1 -P(z^0 \vert X,Y) $ but without sucess. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X\perp Y | Z=0$ does not imply $X\perp Y | Z=1$. E.g. let $(x,y,z)$ be jointly distributed as $(U_1,U_2,0)$ and $(U_1,U_1,1)$ for $U_1,U_2$ iid and independent of $z$.